# PHP, POST data from one row only (id) from WHILE loop, when SUBMIT

Tags: php, post, submit

**Issue**, how can I POST needed data (`id`,`username`, etc.) only for one row, from `while` loop, when `submit`?

**Code** (I am using `POST` as call "function" `delete_member`, with `if` condition, what is better way?).

```
if(isset($_POST["delete_member"]))
{
# Delete member
echo $id=$_POST["id"];
$sql="delete from members where id = $id";
mysqli_query($db,$sql) ? $status = true : $status = false;
message($status);
}

$select_members = mysqli_query($db,"select * from members");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_members))
{
echo('
<tr>
<td><input type="text name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'" readonly></td>
<td><input type="text name="username" value="'.$row['username'].'" readonly></td>
<td><input type="text name="password" value="'.$row['password'].'" readonly></td>
<td><input type="text name="active" value="'.$row['active'].'" readonly></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="delete_member" value="Smazat"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="send_email" value="Odeslat email"></td>
<tr>
');
}
```

Nothing stored in `echo $id=$_POST["id"];`. Is possible send `id` from `input type="submit"`? For example like this.

```
<input type="submit" name="delete_member" id=".$row['id']." value="Smazat">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST["delete_member"]))
{
# Delete member
echo $id=$_POST["id"];
$sql="delete from members where id = $id";
mysqli_query($db,$sql) ? $status = true : $status = false;
message($status);
}

$select_members = mysqli_query($db,"select * from members");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_members))
{
echo('
<tr>
<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
<td>'.$row['username'].'</td>
<td>'.$row['password'].'</td>
<td>'.$row['active'].'</td>

<td><form method="post" action="HERE_FILL_IN_SCRIPT_URL"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'"><input type="submit" name="delete_member" value="Smazat"><input type="submit" name="send_email" value="Odeslat email"></form></td>
<tr>
');
}
```

Comment: Really insert `form` to every row? Isn't there a beter way?

Comment: well u can use checkbox in each row name="id[]" and submit at the end of table then in post you have array of selected ID's

Comment: or just basic link /?id=x and then in php use $_GET['id']

Comment: Yes, I know about link, but I think it is not good method, I want to do it right way, once for all,`GET` is not for sending data. Is not possible just add another parameter (`id`) to `submit`? Another way to do it is for example add `id` to string `delete_member`, for example `"delete_member_'.$row['id'].'"`, and then parse this field...?

Comment: right way is stright in posted answer,no hacks plain solution, but you dont like it

Comment: It is a best way how to do that? I think it will be very slow in case of huge DB, `form` in every row? How do you do that, when you need call function for one row (one `id`)?

Comment: you need a form for every id if you do not want to use JavaScript. You should accept this answer because it highlights the error you had in your code.

Comment: well we use Symfony or Nette frameworks so its different,in general delete action is login protected so using link /delete?id=1 and using $_GET its not bad,processing again check user doing this operetaion or even if he have permission,than we secure  what was "recieved" in that data from that link to prevent some hack (sql injection) and thats it,frameworks do lot of job for you

Comment: @JonasEberle How can I do that with JS? Thanks.

Comment: @TomášMafiVinduška And what about some array? Is possible send two fields in one name as array?

Answer (score -1):

at the end, best method is change `input` to `button`, where `value` is not displayed, so `value` can be `$row['id']` and name is between tags`<button>NAME</button>`.

```
if(isset($_POST["deleteMember"]))
{
# Delete member
$id=$_POST["deleteMember"];
$sql="delete from members where id = $id";
mysqli_query($db,$sql) ? $status = true : $status = false;
message("Smazání člena",$status);
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_members))
{
echo('
<tr>
<td><input type="text name="id[]" value="'.$row['id'].'" readonly></td>
<td><input type="text name="username[]" value="'.$row['username'].'" readonly></td>
<td><input type="text name="password[]" value="'.$row['password'].'" readonly></td>
<td><input type="text name="active[]" value="'.$row['active'].'" readonly></td>
<td><input type="text name="sentEmailAll" value="'.$row['email_sent'].'" readonly></td>
<td><button type="submit" name="deleteMember" value="'.$row['id'].'">Vymazat člena</button></td>
<tr>
');
}
```

But I thing this is not elegant, I believe there is better way to solve similar things.